# Is there a way to wrapAll() but ignore one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If you have the following code:

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <div class="3"></div>
    <div class="4"></div>
    <div class="5"></div>   

</div>
```

How can I wrap a new div around div with class 2,3,4,5 so it looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="1"></div>

    <div class="sub">
        <div class="2"></div>
        <div class="3"></div>
        <div class="4"></div>
        <div class="5"></div> 
    </div> 

</div>
```

wrapAll on the parent would wrap everything with a new div, is there a way to make it ignore the first div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `gt(0)` to select all but the first one div(direct descendant) and wrapAll. This will select all divs with index greater than 0 present under `.parent` div.

```
$('.parent > div:gt(0)').wrapAll('<div class="sub">');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Fxh/)**

See **[:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)**

Output:

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="1">1</div>
    <div class="sub">
            <div class="2">2</div>
            <div class="3">3</div>
            <div class="4">4</div>
            <div class="5">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't that, ignore **till** the first one?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui it will ignore the first one i.e the one with index 0.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui It's saying, `Divs with greater than a 0 index need to be wrapped with a div class of sub`

Comment: @user2413333 DO you care about the class? You just want to ignore the first one right? and i am sure you dont have a class `.1` in your code.

Comment: @PSL NO! If I change the index to `1` it ignores both `1 and 2`

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/m3TUP/. If so yes thats what greater than is supposed to do...

Comment: The only other thing actually, is there a way to not only ignore the first div, but everything inside that div too. Because at the moment this is what happens http://jsfiddle.net/zyeYG/2/

Comment: Thanks very much guys, works perfect now. You are all the best :)

Comment: @PSL check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/zyeYG/1/ changed the selector parameter to `1` and both `1 and 2` got effected! :O

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Areeb that's what it is supposed to Do, Select everything greater than that index. Btw 1 & 2 were un affected you should say.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`not()` filter](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$('.parent div').not('.1').wrapAll('<div class="sub">');
```

Or alternatively:

```
$('.parent div:not(.1)').wrapAll('<div class="sub">');
```

You can also use `div:first-child` in place of `.1` if you always want to ignore the first element.

Comment: Yep. Felt your solution made assumptions it shouldn't have but later changed my mind. Sorry about that. EDIT: Whoa, got a badge out of that.

Comment: No problem, but a comment will always help :). I assumed OP just wanted to ignore the first one hence in the sample code he had the the class named as 1, 2, 3 , 4etc...

Answer (score 1):

If the element you want to keep out is not necessarily the first, you could use:

```
$(".parent div").not("div.1").wrapAll("<div class='sub'>");
```

Although, this will re-order your `div`s so that the wrap comes first, and the unwrapped element comes last. Not a problem when it's the first element, but if it's the third, for example, the output would be:

```
<div class='sub'>
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <div class="4"></div>
    <div class="5"></div>
</div>
    <div class="3"></div>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tomtheman5/3TL4M/

*edit*: Just saw @Corion's answer... This is essentially the same, but with some more information. I'll leave it up.